# XSD validation error: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'soapenv:Envelope'

Tags: xml, xsd

I try to validate my XML against my XSD using http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html but it fails with the error above.
I found many of the same questions but none of the answers helped me.
Please help, what is the correct XML/XSD?

**My XML**: (only the minimal one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" >
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My XSD**: (only the minimal one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  >
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1220667/3364187)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it does not help. I tried to add schemaLocation etc ... but I get only errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Several issues:**

- Your XML does not hint as to the location of an XSD.

  **Remedy**: Use `xsi:schemaLocation` (see XSD below).
- Your XML namespace URI for SOAP is non-standard.

  **Remedy**: Use `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` (note trailing slash).
- Your XSD does not define a `targetNamespace`.

  **Remedy**: Define one, or better yet, use the [standard Schema for the SOAP/1.1 envelope](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/).

You can use the following null SOAP envelope message to check your message; it will eliminate your error and allow the declaration of `soapenv:Envelope` to be found:

### Minimal Valid SOAP Envelope

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
                                      http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
  <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You might think I'm stupid or something but I still getting the same error. I use your SOAP Envelope as XML and my XSD with a added targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  and getting a   ----->  
    Cvc-elt.1: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'soapenv:Envelope'.. Line '4', Column '78'.

Comment: No, it's probably just a simple mistake you're making, but I can't tell without seeing your exact work.   Start here:  Paste the minimal SOAP message from my answer into the validation service.  Use this for the URL field: `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`.  I just checked and it works at your online XPath site: http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html  Once you confirm that this works, take small steps to adjust it to match what you want to do, re-validating each step along the way.

Comment: Yes you are right. If I take your SOAP message and this URL (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) as my XSD than it works! but I know now ( I googled a lot) that I made a mistake and not say that my XML contains more than one namespace (also a custom namespace). So the XML (with SOAP and custom namespace) must validate against a custom (file) XSD. Sorry for the confusions :-(

Comment: That's ok, but I'm not clear on whether you all set now or still need further help.

Comment: I need to rethink my question. Maybe I have to ask another question later. Many thanks !!!!